# Parsing the KML file throwing org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: android, saxparser

I searched the Links but still not getting why i am getting this error :

```
07-20 12:02:59.140: W/System.err(6558): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: expected: /meta read: noscript (position:END_TAG </noscript>@1:495 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41efde28) 
07-20 12:02:59.140: W/System.err(6558):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
07-20 12:02:59.140: W/System.err(6558):     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
07-20 12:02:59.140: W/System.err(6558):     at com.twra.mapview.MyDrivingDirectionsActivity.DrawPath(MyDrivingDirectionsActivity.java:82)
07-20 12:02:59.140: W/System.err(6558):     at com.twra.mapview.MyDrivingDirectionsActivity.onCreate(MyDrivingDirectionsActivity.java:43)
07-20 12:02:59.140: W/System.err(6558):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
07-20 12:02:59.140: W/System.err(6558):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
07-20 12:02:59.150: W/System.err(6558):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 12:02:59.180: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(6558): <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
```

Comment: DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
   doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());


I am getting the error while parsing(in the last line)..
But the url is correct what i have checked in browser(
https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=25.04202,121.534761&daddr=25.05202,121.554761&ie=UTF8&om=0&output=kml)

Comment: So I got this Link https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

The xml document you are trying to parse here `MyDrivingDirectionsActivity.java:82` is not well-formatted.